# iOS7 custom interactive transition, hidden back button reappears as "..." when cancelled

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uikit, uikit-transitions

I have a custom interactive transition which requires me to hide the standard back button. Basically, the transition looks like a push from left-to-right rather than the standard right-to-left push we're all familiar with. That's why my back button is on the right side instead.

As you can see from two screenshots I took before and after cancelling pop transition activated by a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer, once the transition is cancelled there is a "..." where the back button would be.

[image: Before and After Cancelling the transition]

I'm currently using

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

and I've tried putting it in **awakeFromNib**, **viewDidLoad**, **viewDidAppear**, **viewWillAppear** methods all without fixing the problem.

So using the power of Reveal.app I investigated the view hierarchy before and after and saw this:

[image: View hierarchy before and after via reveal.app]

What you see highlighted in each part of the image is what appears to be changing in the area of the nav bar that contains the hidden back button. Before it's a UINavigationButton and then it becomes a UINavigationButtonItem with a UILabel, which must be what contains the "..." and remains like this.

Any help would be much appreciated. I hope this is detailed enough to give a good picture of the issue.

Comment: Can you do a full view hierarchy dump from the debugger with `po [self.view recursiveDescription]`?

Comment: Also, I wonder if the '...' isn't just a truncation of a longer string assigned to the `UILabel`. Find the address of the UILabel (from that recursive description) and do: `po [(UILabel*)0xfoofoo text]`

Comment: I was thinking the same thing re: "..." just being a cut off string. I'll try printing it out. It's possibly the word "Back"

Comment: @JasonMoore So it looks like from the printout the UILabel contains the title of the view I'm popping back to. So I tried removing the title in my storyboard and still had the "..." issues because the UILabel now became "Back" instead. So this appears to be some issue with the back button image hiding but it's label not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an empty backbutton first (in the parent viewcontroller before the vc is pushed) - maybe that will prevent the "..." `UILabel` from being created.

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
      initWithTitle:@""
              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
             target:nil
             action:nil];`

Another idea: Just set the parent vc title to an empty string.

`self.title = @"";`

Comment: I added
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];

in my **prepareForSegue:** call in the parentVC and the problem appears to be gone :)

Comment: I'm not using Storyboards, but I was able to set `.backBarButtonItem = nil` in viewDidLoad and it doesn't seem to reappear. (If that didn't work, I'd use `viewWillDisappear`.